# How can I provide a default bean implementation in Spring MVC with xml configuration?

Tags: java, xml, spring, spring-mvc

I'm working on some old code base and it's using xml configuration.

Basically it has a basic controller named `BaseController` and all other controllers inherit that. Now I need to add an extra service bean which all current controllers need to use. The bean definition is like this:

`<bean id="myService" class="com.myweb.MyService" scope="singleton"/>`

The base controller will also have a field named `MyService myService`, with a null value now.

Instead of setting the property name in the xml file under each existing controller bean mapping (there are too many), how can I set the singleton MyService instance to all controllers at runtime (like a default value instead of null)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can autowire the bean.

Annotate your `BaseController` `MyService` field with

```
@Autowired
private MyService myService;
```

Comment: That doesn't work. In order for @Autowired to work, I need to add the service/controller annotations to existing classes and add the context:component-scan to the xml config, which might conflict with the existing xml bean wiring.

Comment: @NSF What you need is to add the above line and the `<context:annotation-config>` XML element. You don't need `@Service` or `@Controller` annotations if you're already declaring `<bean>` elements for all those classes.